# Instantiate only once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do Instantiate only once? This script continuously create clones.

```
GameObject[] cubeParticules;

void OnTriggerEnter()
{

foreach(GameObject part in cubeParticules) 
{   
    Instantiate(part, temp1, Quaternion.identity);
}
}
```

No scripts attached to cubeParticules

Answer (score 2):

The `foreach` term (if it wasn't obvious enough) performs the contained code **for each** object that is true to the condition; in this case: for each game-object contained in the `cubeParticles` array.

After your edit:
Also, your colliders may be touching each other at multiple entry points.

Try using a bool flag that is set once the objects are initiated, and then reset in `OnTriggerExit()`.

Here's some sample code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    ...
    if (!instantiated)
    {
        foreach(GameObject part in cubeParticules) 
        {   
            Instantiate(part, temp1, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    ...
        instantiated = true;
    }
    ...
}

void OnTriggerExit()
{
    ...
    instantiated = false;
    ...
}
```

I hope that helps!